# How to Change backround image/filter based on the video status

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-api, slider

This is something I have been struggling with for some time. Basically I have a number of image sliders on a single page one above the other, of which the majority have YouTube videos on some of their slides. What I am trying to achieve is to have the background div darken on viewing a video (this part I have achieved) the next part is where I am having difficulties. What should happen next is that when the video stops playing, or is stopped, or the slide is changed the background div is then returned to its default setting (minus the filter). Then on the video being played the background div is then darkened again. Basically when ever the video plays the background should have the filter and when stopped the filter should be removed.

Here is my code so far:

HTML

```
<div class="cheader" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px;">
<div class="Filter"></div>
<i id="cross" class="fa fa-times"></i>

<div class="whitebox" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">[wonderplugin_slider
id="12"]</div>
<div class="whitebox" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">[wonderplugin_slider
id="14"]</div>
<div class="whitebox" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">[wonderplugin_slider
id="5"]
</div>
<div class="whitebox" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">[wonderplugin_slider
id="9"]</div>
<div class="whitebox" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">[wonderplugin_slider
id="10"]</div>
<div class="whitebox" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">[wonderplugin_slider
id="6"]</div>
<div class="whitebox" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">[wonderplugin_slider
id="8"]</div>
<div class="whitebox" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">[wonderplugin_slider
id="2"]</div>
<div class="whitebox" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">[wonderplugin_slider
id="11"]</div>
<div class="whitebox" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">[wonderplugin_slider
id="32"]</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.whitebox { width: 1100px !important; max-width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; display: block !important; background-color: #fff;
 padding: 10px; z-index: 5; }

.postid-291 .cc-postcontent, .postid-293 .cc-postcontent, .page-id-528 .cc-
postcontent { margin-bottom: -30px; line-height: 150%!important;}

#postnav {width: 1100px; max-width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;
display: block !important; height: 50px; padding-bottom: 10px; }

.entry-meta {display: none!important; }


 .Filter { background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9)!important; opacity:0.7; -webkit-
 transition: opacity .25s ease; -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease; position:
 absolute; top:0; left:0; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none; z-index: 
 3;}
```

Javascript

```
//Toggle play video darken background on and off 

$(".wonderpluginslider").on("click", function(e){ //this works
   $(".Filter").show();
   $("#cross").show();     
})


$(".Filter").on("click", function(e){ //this works
   $(".Filter").hide();
  $("#cross").hide();
  location.reload(); 

})


$(".ytp-chrome-controls").on("click", function(e){ //does not appear to work
    $(".Filter").hide();
    $("#cross").hide();
})
```

Any assistance in this matter will be most appreciated. As you can see from my JavaScript that I have tried reloading the window, which works fine, except the client does not want the page to reload, so need to find another solution to this.

Comment: How are you embedding the videos?

Comment: Hi Simon I am using the wonderpluginslider which accepts the YouTube link youtu.be/ixLHJ1NuKW8 and embeds that. When I look at the source code deep within the plugin div containers is an iframe                                    *<iframe  id="amazingslider-video-12" style="display:block;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="737" height="459" src="youtube.com embed/ixLHJ1NuKW8?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&am‌​p;autoplay=1&amp;rel‌​=0&amp; autohide=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fcha‌​choo.co.uk&amp;widge‌​tid=2"></iframe>*